# issue with video_playeur package of flutter

Tags: flutter

Hello I tried the video_playeur package but have crash when I replay multiple time a video... here is the repport :

```
I/ExoPlayerImpl(20516): Init c98f76 [ExoPlayerLib/2.9.6] [herolte, SM-G930F, samsung, 26]
V/Surface (20516): sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
I/ACodec  (20516):  [] Now uninitialized
I/ACodec  (20516): [] onAllocateComponent
I/OMXClient(20516): Treble IOmx obtained
I/ACodec  (20516): [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] Now Loaded
V/Surface (20516): sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
D/SurfaceUtils(20516): connecting to surface 0x756360d010, reason connectToSurface
I/MediaCodec(20516): [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] setting surface generation to 21008428
D/SurfaceUtils(20516): disconnecting from surface 0x756360d010, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
D/SurfaceUtils(20516): connecting to surface 0x756360d010, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
I/MediaCodec(20516): failed to configure codec bacause of codec capacity
E/MediaCodec(20516): Codec reported err 0xffffec77, actionCode 0, while in state 3
D/SurfaceUtils(20516): disconnecting from surface 0x756360d010, reason disconnectFromSurface
E/MediaCodec(20516): configure failed with err 0xffffec77, resetting...
I/ACodec  (20516):  [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] Now uninitialized
I/ACodec  (20516):  [] Now kWhatShutdownCompleted event : 8483
I/MediaCodec(20516): Codec shutdown complete
I/ACodec  (20516):  [] Now uninitialized
I/ACodec  (20516): [] onAllocateComponent
I/OMXClient(20516): Treble IOmx obtained
I/ACodec  (20516): [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] Now Loaded
I/ACodec  (20516):  [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] Now uninitialized
I/ACodec  (20516):  [] Now kWhatShutdownCompleted event : 8483
I/MediaCodec(20516): Codec shutdown complete
W/MediaCodecRenderer(20516): Failed to initialize decoder: OMX.Exynos.avc.dec
W/MediaCodecRenderer(20516): android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0xffffec77
W/MediaCodecRenderer(20516):    at android.media.MediaCodec.native_configure(Native Method)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(20516):    at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:1935)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(20516):    at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:1864)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(20516):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.configureCodec(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:483)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(20516):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.initCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:805)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(20516):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.initCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:745)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(20516):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:474)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(20516):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.reinitializeCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1261)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(20516):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1111)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(20516):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:552)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(20516):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:647)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(20516):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:529)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(20516):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:300)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(20516):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(20516):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(20516):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20516): Playback error.
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20516): com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.Exynos.avc.dec, Format(1, null, null, video/avc, null, -1, null, [1440, 1080, -1.0], [-1, -1])
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20516):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:479)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20516):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.reinitializeCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1261)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20516):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1111)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20516):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:552)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20516):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:647)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20516):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:529)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20516):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:300)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20516):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20516):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20516):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20516): Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.Exynos.avc.dec, Format(1, null, null, video/avc, null, -1, null, [1440, 1080, -1.0], [-1, -1])
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20516):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.initCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:753)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20516):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:474)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20516):     ... 9 more
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20516): Caused by: android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0xffffec77
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20516):     at android.media.MediaCodec.native_configure(Native Method)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20516):     at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:1935)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20516):     at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:1864)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20516):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.configureCodec(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:483)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20516):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.initCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:805)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20516):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.initCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:745)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(20516):     ... 10 more
```

my function

```
   Future<String> create_video() async {

SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString('daysfromnow_modify',daysfromnow_modify)??"";


final Directory extDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
_controller = VideoPlayerController.network(

    'file:${extDir.path}/Movies/$daysfromnow_modify.mp4'

)

..initialize().then((_) {
  setState(() {


      if( _controller!=null){
        _changed(true, "video_chargement"); //display video
      }else{
        _changed(false, "video_chargement"); // hide video
      }

    });

});
```

}
All is good but after 5 replays or 8, or 10,  it's random I have crash

I use the example and only add  _controller.initialize(); to replay video without it, I can't replay finished video. But when controller.initialize(); is call multiple time I have crash...

Comment: share how you have implemented it

Comment: Ok, I have add this

Comment: I have this solution to get around by not use initilized but return the play to zero     if (_controller.value.position >= _controller.value.duration ){
                                                  _controller.seekTo(Duration.zero);
                                                }

Comment: but i have always the ressource issue when I load next video, because I don't know how to reload without use of .initialize()

Comment: Do you need to create SharePreferences, RegExp, Directory inside this method? If this method is getting called numerous times these things will eat memory.

Comment: I don't use RegExp I forgot to hide this, I have upload the function, but need to load sharedpref. problem of crash is related to initialize() for sure.

Comment: This could be due to multiple initialize of ExoPlayer. Try releasing the previous player before new instance. Also, can you list the devices you have tested on? I've seen this issues on many Samsung devices.

Comment: Yes I have a samsung s7, what do you think about releasing  ? if you have a little example from the pacakge

Comment: have you fixed the issue?

Comment: @Saman Salehi no solutions

Comment: You have to release the current video/mediacodec instance before starting another one. This issue can also happen if another application is using `MediaCodec`, like a camera application or another video player. Unfortunately, there is no way to know if the decoder is released by the time you start the next instance. Assuming you are using a `Surface` to display the video, you should release the codec in `onSurfaceTextureDestroyed`. You can check how many instances of `MediaCodec` is supported by calling `getMaxSupportedInstances`, see the docs here - shorturl.at/elw48

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the same VideoPlayerController is being reinitialized multiple times without being disposed. If the same controller is going to be used again, the controller can be reused again as mentioned [GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59833).